# Start baking, register as delegate error

Tags: node, tezos-client

I run command

```
~/tezos/tezos-client register key 607c9c58-13a6-47a7-baf9-9b4ed18ca00d as delegate
```

**607c9c58-13a6-47a7-baf9-9b4ed18ca00d** - alias for remote signer with key *tz3dBCxvKZgoLcCWCgfVZGUPQ8Dd154YRFJM*

and got error

> `Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
>   Estimated gas: 10000 units (will add 100 for safety)
>   Fatal error:
>     Json_encoding.Unexpected_field("tz3LMNSoRATM5FBMas8FkAghxzz8mCvHH3nA")`

my client config

```
{ 
"base_dir": "/home/magomedov/.tezos-client", 
"node_addr": "babylonnet.tezos.cryptium.ch",
"node_port": 8732, 
"tls": false, 
"web_port": 8080, 
"confirmations": 0
```

}

but, when i try get balance, i got result. what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, can you try to run `tezos-client --log-requests register key 607c9c58-13a6-47a7-baf9-9b4ed18ca00d as delegate --dry-run` command and share the output?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fXvCaMw8  
I realized that he can not recognize the answer `/authorized_keys` remote signing server

Answer (score 2):

You are using a remote RPC endpoint. Most public RPCs do not allow injection of operations, which you are trying to do via the "register key" operation. If you want to do this, you will need to use a local node or find a public node that allows injections.

Comment: Be sure to mark as answered please