# Invoke rpc method, return "Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: rpc, alphanet

I access rpc interface of https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443 through postman, and some rpc give me return value, but some return the error:

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

such as, `/chains/<chain_id>/blocks/<block_id>` returned value:
[image]

and `../<block_id>/helpers/parse/operations` returned error:[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `../<block_id>/helpers/parse/operations` is a `POST` method, not `GET`.

Also, it's quite common when owners of public RPC nodes close some endpoints to prevent abusing. If you see an auth error, try to contact the owner, or choose another public RPC node.

Here is the best choice in my opinion: https://tezos.org.ua/#infrastructure

Comment: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/start-baking-register-as-delegate-error/2245#2245